# How to stop inventory reset on logout from dedicated server?

Tags: space-engineers

So, for a while I thought I was dying because of lack of life support wherever I logged out. I've had successful logouts/logins in beds in NPC stations, but now that's not even working.

Whenever I logout, even for just a few minutes, the server seems to just delete my character. When I log back in, it spawns me at the Survival Kit, with a new set of base-level tools, full O2, and full H2. I'd like to log back in to where I log out, and cryochambers are out of reach due to lack of silver for medical components.

How do I stop losing my inventory on logout, and stop being teleported back to my survival kit on login?

EDIT: Okay, so Cryo Pods and beds will work. The problem I had with the bed was that the NPC station I was using has two bedrooms - one downstairs with two beds, and one upstairs with three.  The upstairs bedroom, however, while airtight... has no vent. So I assume what happened is I used up all of the oxygen and died.  The downstairs two-bed has access to the station's O2 system, and I've survived two nights in a row there, now.

So now this question is simply about changing the server settings (or installing a mod) so that players who logout (or crash to desktop) have their inventories preserved (at least as long as they aren't proactively hunted down and killed by weapons fire).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Sleepers' in space engineers are unfortunately not persistent, no mods seem to be able to be made to fix this either (Mods have limitations in SE.) Disconnected 'Sleeper' players will survive a couple of minutes before the game despawns them. A server rollback will give the opportunity for players to take advantage of the brief despawn grace period to recollect their things, in the event of a crash for example.

The 'cheapest' way to not lose gear is to have a respawn point nearby (Say for example a survival kit) and simply let the game kill you on logout with your inventory stowed elsewhere. You do not even need to build a cargo container, seats have a small amount of storage space, enough to hold some tools and a couple of bottles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still collecting data but the trash-collection menu for the server admin seems to have an option for the removal of disconnected players. With that off, it seems that the player model will persist until the environment kills them. Once I've confirmed this with a controlled experiment, I'll score/close the question.